# Rotation going wrong

Tags: opengl, matrix

I'm calculating matrices by hand. Translations are fine:

```
 void Translate (float x, float y, float z, float[4][4] m) {
     Identity (m);
     m[3][0] = x;
     m[3][1] = y;
     m[3][2] = z;
 }
```

If I multiply a vector with this matrix, I get the correct transformation. My problem now is Rotations. I copied the definition from the OpenGL reference on glRotation, but I can't get it right. Can you spot my mistake?

```
void Rotate (float angle, float x, float y, float z, float[4][4] m) {   
    float c = cos (angle);
    float s = sin (angle);
    m[0][0] = x*x*(1-c)+c;
    m[0][1] = y*x*(1-c)+z*s;
    m[0][2] = x*z*(1-c)-y*s;
    m[0][3] = 0;
    m[1][0] = x*y*(1-c)-z*s;
    m[1][1] = y*y*(1-c)+c;
    m[1][2] = y*z*(1-c)+x*s;
    m[1][3] = 0;
    m[2][0] = x*z*(1-c)+y*s;
    m[2][1] = y*z*(1-c)-x*s;
    m[2][2] = z*z*(1-c)+c;
    m[2][3] = 0;
    m[3][0] = 0;
    m[3][1] = 0;
    m[3][2] = 0;
    m[3][3] = 1;
}
```

I don't know what else is relevant, so, if you're kind enough to lend me a hand on this and if I just don't present enough info, just say it.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

**EDIT**
The trouble I'm having is the following: If I do `Rotate (180,0,0,0)`, the vertexes are inverted as intended but the resulting triangle (in this case) is smaller.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are your matrices column major or row major?

Comment: @sarahm: Column major; at least, that is what I think was doing.

Comment: Are you really intending to rotate around the nonsense axis denoted by the null vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient computations are correct. I can think of two things:

- you do not appear to ensure `(x,y,z)` is a unit vector; if the caller does not take care of this, you should divide each component by `sqrt(x²+y²+z²)`.
- the OpenGL convention is to have angles in degrees, and you are using `cos()` and `sin()` directly.

If none of these are your actual problem, you should describe what is going wrong exactly, maybe with a little example.

Comment: +1 -I agree that forgetting to convert from degrees to radians could be the problem here.

Comment: That was it! I forgot to convert to radians! Superb. Thank you community.